# jQuery XML PARSE

Tags: jquery, xml

Lets say i have an xml.. "xml2.xml"

```
<aurora>
<event> abc </event>
<event> abc </event>
<event> abc </event>
<event> 
<subeve> def </subeve>
<subeve> def </subeve>
<subeve> def </subeve>
</event>
<event> 
<subeve> def </subeve>
<subeve> def </subeve>
<subeve> def </subeve>
</event>
</aurora>
```

And there is a jquery code..

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "xml2.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: xmlParser
    });
});
function xmlParser(xml) {
    $(xml).find("event").each(function () {

        $(".slides").append('<b>1');

        $(this).find("subeve").each(function () {
        $(".slides").append('<i>2</i>');
        });
        $(".slides").append('</b>');

    });
}
</script>
```

The output is : `<b>1111</b><i>222</i><b>1</b><i>222</i>`

But i want the output to be.. : `<b>1111<i>222</i>1<i>222</i></b>`

How can i do this..??

My second ques.. Is my first ques really silly??
:-<

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're thinking in terms of markup (`<b>` and then later `</b>`), but once you're dealing with DOM elements, you're dealing with objects, not markup. Specifically, when you do `$(".slides").append("<b>");`, that *creates* a `b` element and appends it to `slides`. It doesn't "open" a `<b>` tag. Then when you later do `$(".slides").append("<i>2</i>");` it creates an `i` element and appends that to slides, *after* the `b` element, not within it. I don't know what jQuery does with `.append("</b>")`, don't do that. :-)

You can either build up elements and append them as you go (appending the `i` elements to each `b`, and appending `b` to `.slides`), or build up a markup string and append it to `.slides` when you're done.

The first option, building up elements, might look like this:

```
function xmlParser(xml) {
  var slides = $(".slides");

  $(xml).find("event").each(function () {

    var b = $("<b>").text("1");

    $(this).find("subeve").each(function () {
      b.append('<i>2</i>');
    });

    slides.append(b);
  });
}
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/uhexaj/2) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/uhexaj/2/edit)

The second option, building up markup, might look like this:

```
function xmlParser(xml) {
  var markup = [];

  $(xml).find("event").each(function () {

    markup.push('<b>1');

    $(this).find("subeve").each(function () {
      markup.push('<i>2</i>');
    });

    markup.push('</b>');
  });

  $(".slides").append(markup.join(""));
}
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/uhexaj/1) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/uhexaj/1/edit)

Comment: Dude that worked... :) ... Thanx a lot.. but can you please explain why my code is producing such result..????

Comment: @FREAKENGINEER: When you do `.append("<b>")`, that *creates* a `b` element and appends it to `slides`. It doesn't "open" a `<b>` tag. Then when you later do `.append("<i>2</i>")` it creates an `i` element and appends that, after the `b` element, not *within* it. I don't know what jQuery does with `.append("</b>")`, don't do that. :-)

Comment: @FREAKENGINEER: Which is faster? Does it really matter? Until/unless you run into a real, specific performance problem, focus on readability and maintainability. In any case, which is faster will depend entirely on the real-life scenario, and could well vary from browser to browser. The version building up elements and adding them "touches" the DOM more often, so could cause more reflows and such; the version building up markup in memory is building up an array, doing a join, and then applying the resulting markup. That may (or may not) be faster, but it's certainly harder to maintain.

Answer (score -1):

If you just want everything to appear in bold, use CSS:

```
.slides{

    font-weight:bold;

}
```

If you want to use HTML tags for some different purpose, I strongly advise you to use some form of templating instead of creating raw HTML with jQuery.